# Fingerprint minutiae Matching using artificial neural network (back propagation) in matlab

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, neural-network, fingerprint

I have already done the fingerprint minutiae extraction which is something like this:

[image]

And ideally I need a neural network in matlab so that it can classify 10 groups of fingerprints using the extracted minutiae images by pattern matching.

I have 3 fingerprint images for each group so I am going train the network with 2 images and test it with 1 image per group.

Would you guys suggest me building up the model by myself like: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html or someone could paste the code that I may use? I have tried some code online but most of them cannot do exactly what I am hoping them to be.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've imported your image to make the question easier to understand. However, you should note that it not usual on Stack Overflow for someone to write you code examples for your project. You should build the model yourself (as you suggest). If you have trouble understanding how the model should be coded, then ask again. Please show your code when you do. The background information of your task is useful, but some example code is the best way to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: I was told by my supervisor that I should use the code online instead of building by myself as this will be far too much for an undergraduate project. Therefore I came to SO and want to get some help or ideas. So far I am using protected code to do the work but the sourcecode will going to cost me 170 euros which I think it's too expensive. I do thinking of building the database and the model by myself on matlab but a bit concern of using too much time by just building it as my project is due in May. Sorry guys if it is a bit off-topic as I am new to SO.

Comment: I am not suggesting you write a neural network or other classifier model from scratch (although in matlab these can be only a very small amount of code). Your problem is most likely understanding enough of the many freely-available models you will find online in order to use one. Matlab has lots of classifiers in its standard libraries which only need 4-5 lines of code to setup and train. If the open-endedness of the task is causing you trouble then perhaps get your supervisor to suggest a suitable model type than you can just look up how it is used in Matlab.

Comment: How do I convert the minutiae points on the image into a database then? The code I was using is from: [code](http://freesourcecode.net/matlabprojects/60334/fingerprint-minutiae-extraction-in-matlab#.VRAMyPmsV8E) It seems that the code does not give out a text to store the points

Comment: no worry I have fixed the problem by adding : `code`A=[ridge_x,ridge_y];